# Does deleting a snapshot from which a new server was cloned knock down the server?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, ubuntu-16.04, devops

So in Google Cloud Platform, I'm setting up a staging server for my job -- I'm not really a dev ops person so I'm not fully sure what happened here but:

- I created a snapshot of the production server
- I created a server out of the snapshot that I took
- I set up SSH using a new key on my local computer, and the ssh connection works to staging
- Checked the external IP to see if the site was loading and it was! Everything was working correctly.

Here's where I think I fucked up but I don't fully understand why or how to fix it:

I deleted the snapshot, and now the external IP doesn't point to anything at all! BUT my ssh connection from local to the server still works! So the server is still up but why can't I access it any more via browser? I'm very confused.

I assumed that since I made a server out of the snapshot, the snapshot's contents were now copied into the new server instance that I created, and I didn't want to be paying for both the new server and the snapshot. Content-wise that seems to be correct since I can still ssh into the correct IP address, but why can't I access via browser?

Should I create a new snapshot and make another server from scratch for my staging site? Is there a way to undo the deletion of the snapshot that I deleted? Or is this totally unrelated, and is it a total coincidence that the browser-access of the site via IP went down like within seconds that i deleted the snapshot? And why the heck is the ssh connection still working totally fine when I connect via terminal locally?

Please help!

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

UGH I figured it out (mostly) -- Turned out that SOMEHOW HTTP and HTTPS connections became disabled for the server. I still have no idea how as i was making http connections right before i deleted the snapshot. Does deleting snapshots that a server is based on edit server settings????